# Controlling the decimal output in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, decimal, calculator, precision

Where would I add the `toFixed` method in this code that calculates an amount so that I can control the decimal to 18 places and so I don't get incorrect calculations.

Right now 100,000 should return `51`, but it is returning `51.00000000000004`

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var qty = $("#qty");
    qty.keyup(function() {
      var total = isNaN(parseInt(qty.val() * $("#price").val())) ? 0 : (qty.val() * $("#price").val())
      $("#total").val(total);
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is right here before you set the value:

```
$("#total").val(total.toFixed(2));
```

Another option is right here after the math:

```
(qty.val() * $("#price").val()).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I need 18 places, so I changed to 18, but the exact values are still coming out different. Now 100,000 is returning 51.000000000000007105, is there a way to keep the 18 places but make sure that exact numbers are returned?

Comment: @DavidClabaugh You're running into the fact that floating point are approximations, and JavaScript numbers not precise enough for that many decimal places. See: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)